# How to have a rounded background in qml TextEdit

Tags: qml, richtext

I'm trying to have a rounded background in qml TextEdit. To something like this:[image]

I tried this:

```
TextEdit{
    id: text
    textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
    text: "<span style=\"color:blue;font-weight:bold;background-color:grey;border-radius:20px\">blue</span>"
}
```

but the border-radius attibute doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Apparently `border-radius` isn't supported by rich text https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/richtext-html-subset.html#css-properties

Comment: How about, moving the rounded background to a Rectangle component, e.g. `Frame { background: Rectangle { color: "grey"; radius: 20 } Text { text: "blue"; color: "blue"; font.bold: true } }` ?

Comment: @StephenQuan sorry I don't think it works for my condition. I'm having a paragraph and may highlight lots of words. So I'm considering put a canvas behind the text and draw rounded background myself

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm below finds words in your `TextEdit` and uses `positionToRectangle` to derive the bounding boxes for each word. It's used in a `Repeater` to paint the `grey` boundary. The word is used to also color the text:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    TextEdit {
        id: textEdit
        width: parent.width
        text: `red
  orange
    yellow
      green
        blue
          indigo
            violet`
        color: "transparent"
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
        Repeater {
            model: {
                var res = [ ];
                var re = /\w+/g;
                var m;
                while ((m = re.exec(textEdit.text)) !== null) {
                    let s = textEdit.positionToRectangle(m.index);
                    let e = textEdit.positionToRectangle(m.index + m[0].length);
                    res.push( {x:s.x,y:s.y,w:e.x-s.x,h:s.height,t:m[0]} );
                }
                return res;
            }
            Label {
                x: modelData.x
                y: modelData.y
                width: modelData.w
                height: modelData.h
                color: modelData.t
                text: modelData.t
                background: Item {
                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        anchors.margins: -2
                        radius: 10
                        color: "grey"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)